# Unexpected data found during save on eloquent / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent, php-carbon

I have one more field on the database over the `created_at` and `updated_at` as `TIMESTAMP` the field name is date.

So i overwritten the method `getDates()` on my model eloquent because i wanted that field be instantiated from Carbon.

```
public function getDates()
{
   return ['date','created_at','updated_at'];
}
```

But when i go to create a new record on the database it throw me an exception:

> InvalidArgumentException Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found.
>   Unexpected data found.

Ps: the value sent from the form is in EU format: `d-m-Y h:i`

I don't know how figure out this problem any suggestion are appreciated

Comment: You have the solution in my answer now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You array returned from getDates was merged with the dafault one resulting in:

```
['created_at','updated_at','deleted_at','date','created_at','updated_at'];
```

so use only 'date' there and should be fine.

---

Try setting up a mutator for 'date' to convert the data from input into timestamp format.
The error you get is not on Eloquent but Carbon.

```
public function setDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['date'] = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i', $value);
}
```

Also there is mistake in the docs, as getDates defines date accessors, not mutators..

Comment: Tried but seem not be this one the problem thanks. Anyway is not merged but is overwritten.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I just now realized what the problem is. Check the edit.

Comment: Yes this is the right answer i tried on this way for see if it work and it does. :) Thanks mate.

Comment: If you are modifying format of any date then use alias name like DB::raw('(case when backup_records.created_at IS NOT NULL then date_format(backup_records.created_at, "%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p") else "Not Available" end) as created_at_text') instead of 'created_at'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i', $request->publishdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your format "d-m-Y h:i"

You must use one of those: UNIX timestamp, date string (Y-m-d), date-time string,  DateTime / Carbon instance

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Answer (score -1):

Even though its a year old issue and I'm placing my input for anyone still struggling even after setting the mutator.

If the html input date element passes the date in atom format(1975-12-25T14:15:16-05:00) then the date mutator won't help. You need to apply the following fix in Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model class at line#2848 to get it work (in laravel#5).

```
$value = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, (new DateTime($value))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```